# Prove recurrence relation for sum $\ R_k (q,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^k*q^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

Let $\ R_o(q,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n q^i$,
$\ R_1(q,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i*q^i$,
$\ R_2(q,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^2*q^i$ etc...

Prove that $\ R_k (q,n) = [n^k*q^{n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^i*\binom{k}{i}*R_{k-i}(q,n)]/(q-1)$

I have tried the following $\ (R_k=R_k(q,n))$. Let

$\ R_k = 1^k*q+2^k*q^2...+n^k*q^n$ (I)

$\ q*R_k = 1^k*q^2+...+n^k*q^{n+1}$ (II)

Subtracting (II) and (I) we get:

$\ (q-1)*R_k= -1^k*q-(2^k-1^k)*q^2-...-(n^k-(n-1)^k)*q^n+n^k*q^{n+1}$

Now, expanding the general term $\ (n-1)^k$ using the binomial theorem we have

$\ (n^k-(n-1)^k)=\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i}*(-1)^{i+1}*n^{k-i}$

And I got stocked here. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Isolating the sum on the right hand side and changing the order of summation :

$$\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^i{k\choose i}\sum_{m=1}^n m^{k-i}q^m=\sum_{m=1}^nq^m\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^i{k\choose i} m^{k-i}\\=\sum_{m=1}^{n}q^l((l-1)^m-l^m)\\=qR_m(q,n-1)-R_m(q,n)\\=(q-1)R_m(q,n)-n^mq^{n+1}$$

which is what we wanted to show. Line 2 follows from the binomial theorem, line 3 from a trivial relabelling of indices and line 4 from the obvious identity $R_{m}(q,n-1)=R_m(q,n)-n^m q^n$.

Comment: Thanks, DinosaurEgg. Your suggestion inspired-me the how to get the answer I wanted.

Comment: $ \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i \binom{k}{i} \sum_{m=1}^n m^{k-i}q^m=\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i \binom{k}{i}\sum_{i=1}^kR_{k-i}(q,n) $ which will give the recursive relation in terms of $R_i$, i=0...k-1

Comment: what you wrote above is not true $\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}\sum_{m=1}^n m^{k-i}q^m=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}R_{k-i}$. I meant to write an answer, and it is complete, there is nothing to figure out here.